# JAK KML java merge text into kml

Tags: java, kml, google-fusion-tables

Does anyone have experience using the JAK kml package? I am attempting to generate a KML file. I am pulling from google fusion tables an already generated polygon object.

How can I pass this into JAK without having to looop through every lat/long pair and call;

.addToCoordinates(-122.3662784465226,37.81884427772081,30)

```
 <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-88.47298,34.99603,0.0 -88.47288,34.99603,
0.0 -88.37504,34.99561,0.0 -88.30513,34.99561,0.0 -88.24958,34.99546,0.0 -88.20006,34.99563,
0.0 -88.20006,34.99564,0.0 -88.09899,34.88335,0.0 -88.10789,34.8091,
0.0 -88.13023,34.64853,0.0 ,0.0 -88.63014,34.99547,0.0 -88.52806,34.99583,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can somehow obtain a list of coordinates you can use the setter in the class LinearRing : setCoordinates(java.util.List coordinates). (http://www.nilab.info/docs/jak091130/de/micromata/opengis/kml/v_2_2_0/LinearRing.html#setCoordinates%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: I guess regardless I would need to process that lat/long list coming from google fusion tables. Its unfortunate I cant treat it as a string and append it to the Document object.

Comment: It might be better for me to actually treat that data from above coming from fusion tables as xml and parse it into a separate kml file so opposed to looping through every lat/long pair which would take a great deal of time.